# Get all controls with attributes from Request.Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I want to get all input controls on postback event.

> this is sample control I have:

```
 <input name="ctl00$ContentBody$dt_62f6f44864ec4c4892ac074da0209ff4
 type="text" value="11.06.2014"
 id="ContentBody_dt_62f6f44864ec4c4892ac074da0209ff4"  
 class="m-wrap span12 date form_datepicker form-control" 
 data-pagetype="main"
 data-groupname="group_DATE"
 data-rowindex="0" data-objtype="Datepicker"
 data-columnname="DATE_FROM" style="width:50px;">
```

> Handle all keys

```
public Collection<ActionContainer.RequestFormParameter> GetFormParameters()
{
   System.Collections.IEnumerator e2 = Request.Form.GetEnumerator();

   while (e2.MoveNext())
   {
       ActionContainer.RequestFormParameter params_;
       String xkey = (String)e2.Current; // output "ContentBody_dt_62f6f44864ec4c4892ac074da0209ff4"
       String xval = Request.Form.Get(xkey); // output "11.06.2014"
       String AttrCollection = ??

       // I try to find control by id but it didn't work for me
   }
}
```

Comment: Are those input tags dynamically generated from client-side or are they already in ASPX page as TextBox server control at design time?

Comment: Judging from the `name` it looks like they are already on the page. If not my answer would not help much...

Answer (score 0):

Attributes aren't included in the Request.Form collection. So you will have to use FindControl to find the Control and Access it's properties. But since all you have is the Control Name (`key`), you will have to be creative in getting the actual `ID`.

Lets assume you have a TextBox with ID `dt_62f6f44864ec4c4892ac074da0209ff4`. In the form post it will be something like `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt_62f6f44864ec4c4892ac074da0209ff4`, so based on that we can extract the `ID` again.

With the ID use FindControl to find the Control, cast is to the correct Control Type and loop it's properties.

```
//loop all the items in the form collection
foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
{
    //check if the key contains a $, in which case it is probably an aspnet control
    if (key.Contains("$"))
    {
        //split the control name
        string[] keyArrar = key.Split('$');

        //get the last part in the array, which should be the ID of the control
        string controlID = keyArrar[keyArrar.Length - 1];

        //try to find the control with findcontrol, in this case with master pages
        object control = this.Master.FindControl("mainContentPane").FindControl(controlID) as object;

        //check if the control exist and if it is a textbox
        if (control != null && control is TextBox)
        {
            //cast the object to the actual textbox
            TextBox tb = control as TextBox;

            //loop all the attributes of the textbox
            foreach (string attr in tb.Attributes.Keys)
            {
                //get the key and value of the attribute
                Response.Write(attr + ": " + tb.Attributes[attr] + "<br>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
data-pagetype: main
data-groupname: group_DATE
data-rowindex: 0
data-objtype: Datepicker
data-columnname: DATE_FROM
```

The demo TextBox on the aspx page.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dt_62f6f44864ec4c4892ac074da0209ff4" runat="server"
    data-pagetype="main"
    data-groupname="group_DATE"
    data-rowindex="0"
    data-objtype="Datepicker"
    data-columnname="DATE_FROM">
</asp:TextBox>
```

As you can see it can be done, it is however a very complicated way...

Comment: There is a problem in there sorry i passed that, i created controls dynamically so i couldt use findcontrol

Comment: That does not matter, you can still use FindControl for dynamically generated buttons, as long as they are regenerated on every PostBack and before my snippet will be used.